# Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes: ' '

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-routing

I just started learning Angular2 and created a sample project in which i need to route between three pages.

I created a RouterModule in the app.module.ts as the following

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    FormsModule,

    RouterModule.forRoot([
    {path:'login',component : loginComponent},
    {path:'logout',component :logoutComponent},
    {path:'home',component : homeComponent}

])
```

my app.component.ts is as the following:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app', // <my-app></my-app>
  providers: [Wakanda],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
```

my loginComponent.ts

```
@Component({
    selector:'login',
    template : `
    <h1>Login</h1>
    `
})
```

my logoutComponent.ts

```
@Component({
    selector:'logout',
    template : `
    <h1>Login</h1>
    `
})
```

my homeComponent.ts

```
@Component({
    selector : 'home',
    template : `
    <h1>Login</h1>
    `
})
```

my app.component.html

```
<header>
    <nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
      <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
        <li> 
            <a routerLink ="./home">Home</a> 
        </li>
        <li class="active">
            <a routerLink="./login">LogIn</a>
        </li>
        <li>  
            <a routerLink="./logout">Log out</a> 
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
<main>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</main>
```

When i compile the program i am getting an error as

> EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes: ''

Can anyone help me in solving this issue

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try setting up some base global routes including an empty route and a catch all route.

Here's an example `app-routing.module.ts`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './page-not-found.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/login',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { enableTracing: true })
    ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule
    ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

This is the `app.module.ts`

```
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
...

@NgModule({
    imports: [
    ...
    AppRoutingModule // Make sure this one is last
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

The `PageNotFoundComponent` is displayed in the `<router-outlet>` (it's a basic component) whenever the route doesn't match any previously defined route and the `''` path matches the empty route (`localhost:4200/`).

You will want your `AppRoutingModule` imported last in your `AppModule` because the router matches routes in the order that they are registered. By importing the 'matches anything' route last you will be sure all other routes are checked first.

Set [`enableTracing`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/RouterModule-class.html) to true for your routes to help debug navigation changes while developing.

This should be a good place to start

Answer (score 0):

I figured the problem, I missed to add the default path in the RouterModule

```
{
  path:'',
  redirectTo:'/login',
  pathMatch:'full'
}
```